# Is there a way to use LINQ to change the 'checked' radio button in a radio button list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater control that houses several RadioButtonLists with various RadioButtons in each list. When my page loads I have several different values. For the sake of clarity let's say I have values "1", "2", and "3". I want to have whichever radio buttons in all of the radiobuttonlists that contain that value to be pre-selected. I already have the RadioButtonLists I want, I just don't know how to access it further.

Is there a way I can do this in LINQ? Something like find the first or default radio button in the radiobuttonlist and checked = true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually over complicating it. All you need to do is change the list.SelectedValue equal to whatever values you already have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure where linq comes into it but you can set the RadioButtonList.SelectedValue property either declaratively or at runtime in the code behind file. This page on MSDN should point you in the right direction:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx

Alternatively post your ASPX and ASPX.CS code and I'd be happy to be a bit more specific.